# Dunn's test p-values in R are exactly half those in SPSS and GraphPad for the same data

Tags: r, nonparametric, dunn-test

Firstly, this is my first post to Cross Validated, so apologies in advance if I have infringed any conventions.

I am writing up a PhD thesis on aspects of biomedical research, and use R for my statistics. However, I always check some of the data against another package in case I have made a coding error.

I have been running a Kruskall-Wallis test with three groups (sample sizes of 5, 8 and 9) and using Dunn's test for the post-hoc pairwise comparisons. The p-values I get for the pairwise comparisons (unadjusted for multiple comparisons) are exactly half what I get in SPSS and GraphPad for the same data. The Kruskal-Wallis p-value reported by the dunn.test package is exactly what I get running the Kruskal-Wallis test itself in R, or in SPSS and Graphpad. There is a warning after I run my code that the dunn.test package was written on a slightly later version of R, but that seems unlikely to be the cause of a factor of 2 variation. Has anyone else come across a similar discrepancy?

Comment: +1 for double checking with a different package. That said, I'm not familiar with Dunn's test, but [the documentation for the `dunn.test` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dunn.test/dunn.test.pdf) notes that it uses a one-sided test, which would give you a p value half as large as a corresponding two-sided test (assuming a symmetrical distribution, which would be the only type that would make sense here). Is it possible that the other packages use a two-sided test?

Comment: Good point, I'll look into it.

Comment: I got my doubles and my halfs muddled up, so I have amended the question. The p-values in R are smaller than those in the other two packages.

Comment: I suspected as much in my comment above. Could you find out whether SPSS & GraphPad do two-sided tests?

Comment: It looks like SPSS does a two-sided test, so you seem to be thinking along the right lines (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/alg_nonparametric_multiple-comparisons_pairwise.htm). Is a two-sided test similar to a two-tailed t-test? In other words, it makes no assumptions about which group in each comparison is going to be larger?

Comment: Exactly! Any symmetric test statistic distribution can be used to build a one-sided or a two-sided test, and the familiar two-tailed $t$ test is simply a two-sided test using the $t$ distribution. As I said, I'm not familiar with Dunn, but the question appears appropriate for a two-sided test, so it does not make a prior assumption about which group will be larger. You will need to consult your prior knowledge to figure out which test is appropriate.

Comment: OK, many thanks! It also seems that GraphPad also runs a two-side test (http://www.graphpad.com/support/faqid/1156/). It should be noted that GraphPad does not show the unadjusted p-values, but these can be calculated by dividing by the number of pairwise comparisons (ie it uses a Bonferroni adjustment).

Comment: I have now found a function dunnTest in a rather obscure package called {FSA} (Fisheries Stock Assessment) which runs a two-sided Dunn's test. I think we therefore have enough information to formally answer my question. Do you want to do that @Stephan_Kolassa, or shall I?

Comment: You have dug up a lot of info that you certainly know better than I. Can you self-answer? I'll happily upvote.

Answer (score 3):

The `dunn.test` package in R uses a one-sided test, whereas SPSS and GraphPad use two-sided tests. There is no facility in the `dunn.test` package or its function `dunn.test()` to change to a two-sided test, but the p-values can be multiplied by 2 if a two-sided test is required.

A two-sided Dunn's test is available from the `dunnTest()` function in package `FSA` (Fisheries Stock Assessment). This package is not available from CRAN, but can be downloaded by running the code `source("http://www.rforge.net/FSA/InstallFSA.R")`. It requires an R version more recent than 3.0.2, and I had trouble installing it until I updated the `Rcpp` package from CRAN. More information on FSA can be found on https://fishr.wordpress.com/fsa/, and documentation on the `dunnTest()` function can be found on http://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/FSA/dunnTest.html.

Thanks to Stephan Kolassa for his help in resolving this problem.

Comment: FSA is a useful package for general users for summarizing data and conducting a few specific tests.  It is now available on CRAN.

Comment: @SalMangiafico (and Mark Birtwhistle),  dunntest does not report one-sided *p*-values. A one-sided *p*-value either takes the form $p=P\left(Z \le z\right)$ or the form $p=P\left(Z \ge z\right)$. However, dunntest gives *p*-values of the form $p=P\left(Z \le |z|\right)$, which is a two-sided test statistic. The correct rejection for this expression of the *p*-value is to reject Ho if $p\le \alpha/2$. Notice that "Reject Ho if $p\le \alpha/2$" ***always*** gives the same test rejection results as  "Reject Ho if $2p\le \alpha$". So there is no "irresponsibility" here.

Comment: @SalMangiafico However, enough folks—including yourself—have expressed a desire for dunntest (and dunn.tst in Stata) to express p-values as you expect them, so I am adding an option to do just that (and to make the rejection criteria explicit in the output). Squeaky wheels get the grease. :)

Comment: As a follow-up on the changes to the `dunn.test` function, the `altp = TRUE` option will return what we think of as the two-sided p-value corresponding to the `Reject Ho if p <= alpha` decision rule.